# Miss co-ordering in commit mechanism between two databases

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, pragma

I'm working on pl/sql `procedure(X)` at `database(A)` it must pass parameters to another `procedure(Y)` at `database(B)` both databases are oracle,
I already create database link from `(A)` to `(B)` and it's work fine.
Problem is when `procedure(X)` executed it return `ORA-02064 ( distributed operation not supported)` which it caused by miss co-ordering in commit mechanism between `(A)` and `(B)`.

I try to use `pragma autonomous_transaction` inside the calling as follow:

```
begin
v_sql :=
            'declare
            pragma autonomous_transaction;
            begin '
            || schema_name
            || '.procedure_Y@'
            ||  db_link
            || '(:1, :2, :3); end;'
                    
execute immediate v_sql using in x , in y, out z;
end;
```

I already use pragma in the declaration of `procedure(X)` and there is no change still get same error,

knowing that I can't modify any object in `database(B)`.

Comment: What do you mean by "missed co-ordering in commit mechanism"?  Is B an Oracle database or are you creating a database link to a non-Oracle database?  When you say that you can't modify objects in B, are you really trying to say that database B is open in read-only mode?

Comment: I mean by _"missed co-ordering in commit mechanism"_ is a commit is issued by `procedure_Y` with OUT parameters which it caused ORA-02064 later.
both databases are oracle , I don't have the privilege to edit any object in `database(B)`  _but it's not in read-only mode_ because it is form different vendor